# window.open() in new tab are not subject to pop-up blockers

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to open new tab window on some condition for example:

```
var temp=true
if(temp)
   window.open('test.aspx');
```

My problem is `window.open()` in new tab should not subject to pop-up blockers. 
I have tried `window.open('viewReport.aspx', '_newtab' );` and `window.open('viewReport.aspx', '_blank' );`, but its always subject to pop-up blocker.

Please provide any solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Window.open will force opening a new tab with a given URL. This is called a Pop-Up.
You cannot control it.

Instead use javascript to simulate a windows by using ex. https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ or http://fancybox.net. Both works with ajax request so you can pull the html content from another page.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is window.open() in new tab should not subject to pop-up blockers.

You might think that but the people writing web browsers do not.

You cannot open a new tab or window from JavaScript except in response to a user event.

The solution is to find some other way to present your information (such as providing the user with a link to it or placing it in the same page).

Answer (score 0):

Create a jquery popup div in ‘on click trigger’ event, that pop up displays with opacity background and it will remains center the popup if you scrolling zoom out the browser and closing it fadeout, and also you can customize the content of the popup div for your cool website designs.

Working example: http://istockphp.com/jquery/creating-popup-div-with-jquery/#sthash.5HcIfl8n.dpuf